# Passing Variable to Partial - undefined local variable or method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is the code in my view to call the partial:

```
<%= render(:partial => "tabs", :locals => {:class_Name => "Science", :y => 36}) %>
```

and now here is what's in _tabs.html.erb:

```
<div>
<h1> <%= class_Name %> </h1>
</div>
```

I expect HTML output of:

```
<div>
<h1> Science </h1>
</div>
```

But instead I get the error:

```
undefined local variable or method `class_Name' for #<#<Class:0x007f873b156c28>:0x007f873b1f9540>
```

I have closed and restarted Aptana (the IDE I use), and restarted the server multiple times

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Can you print the content of the `y` local variable?

Comment: This problem happens to me when I use a symbol with an `?` character at the end, or when I don't send it on the locals hash (this because I don't want to send always that param, so I have to ask if exists before use it). For example: `<% if local_assigns.key?(:is_active) %>`

Answer (score 76):

I've noticed that if I did not include *'partial:'* before my partial path, like so:

```
<%= render 'my_partial', :locals => {:class_Name => "Science", :y => 36} %>
```

I was required to use the hash+symbol in my partial to access the desired values as others have noted.

```
<div>
<h1> <%= locals[:class_Name] %> has a y value of <%= locals[:y] %></h1>
</div>
```

However, including 'partial:' before my partial path:

```
<% render partial: 'my_partial', :locals => {:class_Name => 'Science', :y => 36 } %>
```

...allowed me to simply call the hash values directly.

```
<div>
<h1><%= class_Name %> has a y value of <%= y %></h1>
</div>
```

Just something to keep in mind, this issue tripped me up for awhile when trying to send the locals hash to my partial.

Comment: I have used multiple times the syntax without the hash+key, AFAIK there is no reason why you should be forced to do that (as you're suggesting).

Comment: Thanks @lucke84, I was having trouble figuring out why I needed to include the hash name in my partial. I believe I figured out why after playing with my code some more, it seems I was not specifying 'partial:' before my partial path in the render statement which made the difference. I've revised my answer.

Comment: Thanks for this - in my case as well, specifying `partial` was key.

Answer (score 24):

If you are using the term `partial:` in your render, for example like so:

`<% render partial: 'your_partial', locals: {foo: 'Biggs', bar: 'Wedge'} %>`

Then your locals will be available simply as `foo` and `bar`, directly accessibly thus:

```
<%= foo %> //returns Biggs 
<%= bar %> //returns Wedge
```

However, If you are **NOT** using the term `partials:` in your render, for example like so:

`<% render 'your_partial', locals: {foo: 'Biggs', bar: 'Wedge'} %>`

Then your locals will be available as members of `locals`, accessible thus:

```
<% locals[:foo] %> //returns Biggs
<% locals[:bar] %> //returns Wedge
```

Comment: It's `partials:` or `partial:` ?

Comment: it is `partial:` @alex

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<%= render partial: "form" , locals:{ name_you_want_use_in_partial: @varialble_to_pass } %>
```

I had the same problem. 
So I looked into a documentation [Ruby on Rails - passing local...](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables) and I used fllowing notation - now it's working :)

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine with me.. where is your `_tabs.html.erb` located at?

Comment: it's located in the same folder as the view that calls it. all the other html tags from the partial show up fine.. it's just the local variable substitution that isn't coming through

Comment: Did you try to restart your server or PC? it might be help or try to clear your cache. It's working fine on me.. I used your code and create a `_tabs.html.erb on the same directory`

Comment: Yeah, I have restarted both several times

Comment: Try to remove parethesis....
so it should look like this:

`<%= render :partial => "tabs", :locals => {:class_Name => "Science", :y => 36} %>`

Did you clear your cache and restart your browser?

Comment: That's kinda weird... I haven't seen anything wrong with your code.. After Clearing your cache did you restart your browser?

Comment: Rails 3.2.13. Yes, I cleared the browser cache, restarted, used incognito mode, then used Safari. No luck!

Would it be beneficial to paste all of my code?

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me also. I was using Middleman and it was working fine using `middleman server`, but when i builded my site using `middleman build` i had the error mentioned in the question. I tried all methods described above, but none of them worked. Turns out that in the build phase, middleman tried to build the partials too as a standalone html file, thus producing the error. The reason for this is because i forgot to prefix the filename with an underscore to exclude it from the build process. If all else fails, just wrap your code in an if statement in the partial like so:

```
<% if defined?(class_Name) %>
...
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it had nothing to do with how I was passing instance variables into the partial, but it was **because rails detected variables inside the partial that *were not* provided to the partial**

You could get the error for that very simple reason (in which case there could be absolutely nothing wrong with your code calling the partial - check the partial code for any variable that you didn't provide to it)